# How to remove the edit request i sent In google docs

Tags: google-docs

I accidentally requested edit access in google docs. How to remove edit-request I sent to the owner before the owner knows about the request.

But I don't want this person to see this and to know my new email address. This is really important. Is there any way I can take back this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't take it back, once you request access you send an email and there is no way to take it back.

Answer (score -4):

here is an easy way to take it back because i sent a edit request and i knew i would get in trouble so you can just hit request acses thing and write a letter saying sorry i sent a request please forgive me

Comment: Thanks, Clark you saved my day! I asked for forgiveness and I got it! Thanks again.